# Stack Overflow Visual Studio project type

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, architecture, technology

What project type is used for SO in Visual Studio?  "Web Site" or "Web Application"?  Why?

Answer (score 8):

ASP.NET MVC Web Application according to the [StackOverflow blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/).

Answer (score 1):

As for reasons, one thing Jeff has mentioned is that ASP.NET MVC makes having clean url's easy. So they get friendly, searchable, logical url's like `../questions/{id}` without any additional work.